# How can i get substract between 2 date in Android?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have picked up a date from date picker and another from currently system time. when I want to subtract 2 date what one of them is before 2000 I get some invalid answer for year. how can I resolve it?

```
public class Duration {
    private int year,month,day,hour,min,seconds;

    public Duration(long endTime, long startTime){
        Calendar calendar1=new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar1.setTimeInMillis(endTime);
        Calendar calendar=new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(startTime);
        this.year=calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR)-calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.month=calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH)-calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        this.day=calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        this.hour=calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR)-calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        this.min=calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE)-calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        this.seconds=calendar1.get(Calendar.SECOND)-calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        System.out.println(toString());
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return year+" "+month+" "+day+" "+hour+" "+min+" "+seconds;
    }
}
```

**when  I want to subtract a date in 1998/2/jan from current time I get this result :**

```
-1879 1 3 10 24 34
```

what the year isn't  correctly.

Comment: Please search. There are hundreds of answers already on how to calculate the difference between dates.

Comment: yes but no one of them works for before 2000

Comment: Hundreds of incorrect answers? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `new Duration(883_699_200_000L, System.currentTimeMillis())` prints `-21 -1 -2 -8 -22 -31`, which appears to me to be correct. Your problem is not in the code you have posted, it is somewhere else. Could you provide a reproducible example, please? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Rather than rolling your own `Duration` class consider using one from a library. [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) from [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) seems to be the obvious choice.

Comment: [I downvoted because lacking an MCVE makes it hard to answer](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) and because your code works fine also for years before 2000, so there is no real question here.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("2018-05-26", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("2018-05-28", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
Duration diff = Duration.between(d1.atStartOfDay(), d2.atStartOfDay());
long diffDays = diff.toDays();
```

You will get the number of days in long format. Also refer this answer by Mark Byers.

Comment: Very good to show the use of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. If years and months are wanted, we need to use `Period` rather than `Duration`.

Comment: And for backward compatibility see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746847/295004)

Comment: can you describe it more?

Comment: You will get the number of days in long format. Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829586/8601451

Comment: `Duration` is the wrong class to use here. That class tracks days as 24-hour chunks of time without regard to the calendar. Instead, use `Period`.

Answer (score 1):

**Method: 1**

```
 try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = new java.util.Date();
    Date date2 = df.parse("04-02-2019 12:00:00");
    long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(diff);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.e("Diff Year" , year+ " --" + diff);
    Log.e("Diff Value" , date1.getTime() + " -- " + date2.getTime() + " --" + diff);

} catch (ParseException e){
    Log.e("Diff Value", "Exception", e.getMessage().toString());
}
```

**Method: 2**

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("2017-04-02", 
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("2018-04-04", 
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
Duration dateDifference = Duration.between(d1.atStartOfDay(), 
d2.atStartOfDay());
long dayDifference = dateDifference.toDays();
```

- Subtract Two dates and add difference value in  `Calendar` Object and 
  retrieve Year value from its Object.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate               // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.of( 1999 , 1 , 23 )    // Use factory methods to instantiate rather than constructors, in the *java.time* classes.
.minusWeeks( 12 )       // Do date-math with `plus…` and `…minus` methods.
.toString()             // Generate text as a `String` object with text representing the date value in standard ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM-DD
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/MTGzyw).

> 1998-10-31

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `Calendar` or `Date` classes. Those terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `Period`

To represent a span-of-time in terms of years-months-days, use `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.ofDays( 5 ) ;
```

## Date-time math

You can perform addition and subtraction of date-time values in *java.time* by calling the `plus…` and `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate later = ldt.plus( p ) ;
```

## `Duration`

If you want to represent a span-of-time in terms of days (24-hour chunks of time, unrelated to calendar), hours, minutes, seconds, and fractional second, use `Duration`.

## Year

Your question not clear, but seems to be about the year 2000. There is nothing special about that year with the *java.time* classes.

You can interrogate the *java.time* classes for their year value.

```
int year = ld.getYear() ;
if( year < 2000 ) { … }
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).